# rails > 3.1 development environment: how do I refernce images in app/assets/images in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I have an image in `app/assets/images`

How do I reference this in a view in my development environment?

```
=image_tag 'image.png'
```

looks for the image in `public/assets`. I'm guessing that the image will get copied from `app/assets/images` to `public/assets` once the app is deployed. What am I missing here? I'd appreciate any help.

**Update**

I'm wondering why

`=image_tag 'image.png'` doesn't correctly route to the image in `app/assets/images` with rails in development mode. The image renders as missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue solved itself somehow. Sprockets now correctly routes to the image in `app/assets/images`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct.

In development mode the requests to `public/assets` are handled by Sprockets and mapped to the correct file.

In production mode all the assets are precompiled. There is a rake task for this that needs to be included in your deployment process. This task fingerprints the assets and puts them into the public/assets folder.

Rails keeps a copy of the mappings between files referenced by helpers and what the actual name (with fingerprint) is to allow the fingerprinted name to be used in production automatically.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my question is: why isn't sprockets correctly mapping to the image in app/assets/images ?

Comment: I am not sure. If this is an upgraded app, check that all you pipeline setting match those in the upgrading section of the pipeline guides.